# событие опускание шторки

Tags: android

Можно ли как-то определить в приложении, что шторка (notification bar) опущена и закрывает какую-то часть activity?

Comment: нет, максимум, возможно, в этот момент Activity уходит в background, и у него вызывается метод onPause

Comment: onPause не дергается, в том то и дело

Answer (score 2):

Тоже мучилась с этим. 
В итоге для моего случая подошло использование переопределенного метода `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` активности.

Мне важно было отследить, когда активность теряет фокус, в том числе опущен статус бар.

```
 @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (!hasFocus) {
            // Действия при потере фокуса приложением (в т.ч. при опускании статус бара)
        }             
    }
```

Вот пример, как я контролирую поведение активности при взаимодействии пользователя со статус баром, и перехватах фокуса другими активностями.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (gameFragment!=null) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (frag == gameFragment) {
                gameFragment.saveTimer();
                isTimerPaused = true;
                Log.i("TAG", "MainActivity onWindowFocusChanged isTimerPaused " + isTimerPaused);
            }
        } else if (isTimerPaused) {
            gameFragment.loadTimer();
            isTimerPaused = false;
            Log.i("TAG", "MainActivity onWindowFocusChanged isTimerPaused " + isTimerPaused);
        }
    }
}
```

Если такой общий способ подойдёт, хорошо) Потому что я не нашла, как перехватить именно событие опускания шторки.. Рада буду, если знающие люди дополнят в комментариях, как можно усовершенствовать или изменить мой способ решения поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нету доступа к шторке нотификаций, это системное приложение отвечает за него. OnPause вашего активите в этот момент не будет вызываться.